# Nswag throwing an error message on a simple get trying to consume it

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I am blind or am simply not seieng the issue here. I am using nswagger to gen my clients and am getting an issue with the models

```
@code {
private Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>>? customers;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var test =new  TraditioWebApIClient(Constants.BaseUrl,new HttpClient());
    customers = await test.GetAllCustomersAsync();
}
}
```

Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address>? Addresses { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyType { get; set; }
    public Company? Company { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? Dob { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Mobile { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; } 
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? Region { get; set; }
    public string? PostalCode { get; set; }    
  
}
```

Now the error I get is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
> 'Task<IEnumerable>' because 'Task<IEnumerable>'
> does not contain a public instance or extension definition for
> 'GetEnumerator'       D:\GitMaster\Traditio\Traditio.Blazor\Pages\Customers.razor 29

Nswagger generated this for the method call.

```
/// <returns>Success</returns>
/// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
public virtual 
     System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>> 
        GetAllCustomersAsync()
{
        return GetAllCustomersAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
}
```

I just dont no why the error is their as you see am expecting a task here.

```
private Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>>? customers;
```

**Edit 2**
Output window output

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Traditio.Models.Customer>' to
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Traditio.Models.Customer>>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: try looking at the errors in the Output VS window instead

Comment: @buga same error see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` **runs the task**, returning its value.

In this case, when the task is run, the returned value has type:
`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>`.

Which obviously can't go into `customers`, as the error message indicates.

Add to question an example code snippet, showing how you intend to use `customers` later.

Once you've shown how you will use `customers` later, it will be possible to tell you the needed code correction.

Two possibilities:

- You really do intend `customers` to be a task, rather than an enumeration of customers. In this case, consider renaming it `customersTask`. I'll add to answer the other code changes you need.
- You meant to have `customers` be an enumeration of customers. Change its declaration to:
  `private System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Customer>? customers`.